# Haskell: Double every 2nd element in list

Tags: haskell

I just started using Haskell and wanted to write a function that, given a list, returns a list in which every 2nd element has been doubled.

So far I've come up with this:

```
double_2nd :: [Int] -> [Int]
double_2nd [] = []
double_2nd (x:xs) = x : (2 * head xs) : double_2nd (tail xs)
```

Which works but I was wondering how you guys would write that function. Is there a more common/better way or does this look about right?

Comment: I think your code above lacks the case where the list contains a single element. 
I would add `double_2nd [x] = [x]` after the `[] = [] ` match

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's not bad, modulo the fixes suggested.  Once you get more familiar with the base library you'll likely avoid explicit recursion in favor of some higher level functions, for example, you could create a list of functions where every other one is `*2` and apply (zip) that list of functions to your list of numbers:

```
double = zipWith ($) (cycle [id,(*2)])
```

Comment: List comprehension: `double lst = [f x | (x,f) <- zip lst $ cycle [id,(*2)]]`

Comment: @Ankur If you must, parallel list comprehension is cleaner to read because you can avoid constructing and destructing a tuple.  `double lst = [f x | x <- lst | f <- cycle [id,(*2)]]`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Cool... I didn't knew about this parallel thing :)

Comment: This can be generalized to `mapCyclic fs = zipWith ($) (cycle fs)`, which can be pointfree'd to `mapCyclic = zipWith id . cycle`, which I find quite elegant! So then `double = mapCyclic [id, (*2)]`.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this over `double = zipWith (*) (cycle [1,2])`?  Seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess No, I don't think there is a strong argument against your solution.  If it were a debate the best defense I could provide is that you don't know `1` is multiplicative identity for the `Num` instance of choice (yes, it would be a totally lame Num instance).

Comment: @SeanClarkHess Another bad argument (again, I think your solution is fine but treating this as a debate here) is that by multiplying by one you have the possibility of performing an additional allocation.  For example, in a number theory library I made the numbers were polynomials with coefficients modulus of GF2X and their allocation was expensive.  Thus, unless I had added the appropriate rewrite rules, the extra multiply would allocate (via FFI) an additional heap element for `1` and another heap element for the result.

Answer (score 22):

You can avoid "empty list" exceptions with some smart pattern matching.

```
double2nd (x:y:xs) = x : 2 * y : double2nd xs
double2nd a = a
```

this is simply syntax sugar for the following

```
double2nd xss = case xss of
    x:y:xs -> x : 2 * y : double2nd xs
    a -> a
```

the pattern matching is done in order, so `xs` will be matched against the pattern `x:y:xs` first. Then if that fails, the catch-all pattern `a` will succeed.

Comment: That's cool!
Just as a curiosity (I am not that into Haskell, unfortunately), what does prevent the pattern matcher to choose the second `duble2nd` even for a list that would match the pattern of the first?
Is their order or there is something more complex going on?

Comment: @mariosangiorgio: the standard interpretation for pattern matching is "top to bottom, left to right". You may do some reordering, as long as you make the same choice as the standard interpretation does.

Comment: @Rhymoid thank you for your answer! Can you please clarify what do you mean with "left to right"?

Comment: @mariosangiorgio: A constructor can have multiple fields (e.g. `(:)` has two fields). Left-to-right refers to the fields of constructors, top-to-bottom refers to a list of alternatives.

Answer (score 10):

A little bit of necromancy, but I think that this method worked out very well for me and want to share:

```
double2nd n = zipWith (*) n (cycle [1,2])
```

zipWith takes a function and then applies that function across matching items in two lists (first item to first item, second item to second item, etc).  The function is multiplication, and the zipped list is an endless cycle of 1s and 2s.  zipWith (and all the zip variants) stops at the end of the shorter list.

Comment: You can reduce this by removing `n` on both sides, i.e. `double2nd = zipWith (*) (cycle [1,2])`

Comment: Where/how does the input list go, then?  [zipWith needs three arguments](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zipWith_f.html); what would you expect dropping n?

Comment: Try it and see! We provide `zipWith` with the first 2 arguments (i.e. we partially apply it), which creates a function that still expects the last argument. We then name that function `double2nd` and we're done. There's no need to name the argument in this case. This simplification is called eta-reduction. The argument that we eliminate must be the last one, but we can just swap `n` and the `cycle` in this case, since we are multiplying, so the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

Try it on an odd-length list:

```
Prelude> double_2nd [1]
[1,*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

And you can see the problem with your code.  The 'head' and 'tail' are never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For odd-lists or double_2nd [x] you can always add

```
    double_2nd (x:xs) | length xs == 0 = [x] 
                      | otherwise = x : (2 * head xs) : double_2nd (tail xs)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand why your code is extremely slow for long lists?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [`foldr`-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534683/849891).

```
bar :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
bar xs = foldr (\ x r f g -> f x (r g f)) 
               (\ _ _ -> []) 
               xs 
               (:)
               ((:) . (*2))
```

Testing:

```
> bar [1..9]
[1,4,3,8,5,12,7,16,9]
```