# Double every other element of list from right in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list and I want to double every other element in this list from the right.

There is another related question that solves this problem but it doubles from the left, not the right: [Haskell: Double every 2nd element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383169/haskell-double-every-2nd-element-in-list)

For example, in my scenario, [1,2,3,4] would become [2,2,6,4], and in that question, [1,2,3,4] would become [1,4,3,8].

How would I implement this?

Comment: write a map function based on index of the element.

Comment: I understood the question differently from those who have provided answers so far.  It seems that Hossein wants `[1,2,3] -> [1,4,3]` not `[2,2,6]`

Comment: @TomEllis I agree. I think my answer efficiently solves this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24178579/803801

Comment: Seems like you're trying to solve an exercise from Brent Yorgey's Haskell course: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/hw/01-intro.pdf

Answer (score 17):

I think that the top answer misinterpreted the question. The title clearly states that the OP wants to double the second, fourth, etc. elements from the right of the list. Ørjan Johansen's answer is correct, but slow. Here is my more efficient solution:

```
doubleFromRight :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleFromRight xs = fst $ foldr (\x (acc, bool) ->
                                  ((if bool then 2 * x else x) : acc,
                                   not bool)) ([], False) xs
```

It folds over the list from the right. The initial value is a tuple containing the empty list and a boolean. The boolean starts as false and flips every time. The value is multiplied by 2 only if the boolean is true.

Answer (score 11):

OK, as @TomEllis mentions, everyone else seems to have interpreted your question as about odd-numbered elements from the left, instead of as even-numbered from the right, as your title implies.

Since you start checking positions from the right, there is no way to know what to double until the end of the list has been found.  So the solution cannot be lazy, and *will* need to temporarily store the entire list somewhere (even if just on the execution stack) before returning anything.

Given this, the simplest solution might be to just apply reverse before and after the from-left solution:

```
doubleFromRight = reverse . doubleFromLeft . reverse
```

Comment: His title doesn't match his explanation.  The one he links doubles the 2nd and the 4th.  And he says in my scenario double the first and the third and in that view double the 2nd and 4th.

Comment: @DiegoNolan He doesn't use the words first and third, he just provides example lists.  Since he only gives even-length examples, it is ambiguous from those which of our interpretations he means, except that the title clearly says "second element of list from *right*".

Comment: It is not ambigous.  He links a post that doubles the second, fourth, sixth and so on. And says that is not what he wants.  There is only one other way.  And the lists he displays are excatly what I said.

Comment: @DiegoNolan You think think he wants the *first, third* etc. elements from the *left*. I think he wants the *second, fourth* etc. elements from the *right*. Because the title of this question is "double **second element of list from right** in haskell". These give the same result for the even length example he gives, but different results for odd length ones like the one TomEllis suggests.

Comment: I believe that your interpretation of the problem is correct @ØrjanJohansen. However, I think my solution is more efficient: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24178579/803801

Comment: The course work that this comes from (http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf) hints at the use of reversing the list by asking you to creating a `toDigitsRev` function before creating this. Also the whole list gets summed after so the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 8):

Think about it.

```
double = zipWith ($) (cycle [(*2),id])
```

**EDIT**  I should note, this isn't really my solution it is the solution of the linked post with the `(*2)` and `id` flipped.  That's why I said think about it because it was such a trivial fix.

Comment: Most definitely, `double` is a bad name for this. But nice solution!

Comment: @shang It probably is but I don't know if ghc would optimize `(*1)` to `id`.  It shouldn't for floating point numbers because that would make no sense.

Comment: @DiegoNolan: I'm not sure about GHC's optimizations but from what I understand, 1.0 is the multiplicative identity even for floating point numbers.

Comment: The OP explicitly asking for doubling every 2nd element _from the right_. This answer does it from the left, so if the length of an input list is odd, the result will be wrong.

Comment: @PetrPudlák You're correct - although a `reverse` of the list before using something like appears to be the expected way of handling the problem based on the coursework that this comes from

Answer (score 4):

A direct implementation would be:

```
doubleOddElements :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleOddElements [] = []
doubleOddElements [x] = [2 * x]
doubleOddElements (x:y:xs) = (2*x):y:(doubleOddElements xs)
```

Comment: This doubles every element from the left, not the right.

Comment: I used this solution sandwiched in `reverse`: `doubleOddFromRight = reverse . doubleOddElements . reverse`.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so not elegant or efficient like the other answers, but I wrote this from a beginners standpoint (I am one) in terms of readability and basic functionality.

This doubles every second number, beginning from the *right*.

Using this script: `doubleEveryOther [1,3,6,9,12,15,18]` produces `[1,6,6,18,12,30,18]` and                `doubleEveryOther [1,3,6,9,12,15]`    produces `[2,3,12,9,24,15]`

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther (x:[]) = [x]
doubleEveryOther (x:y:zs)
  |  (length (x:y:zs)) `mod` 2    /= 0    =    x : y*2 : doubleEveryOther zs
  |  otherwise                            =    x*2 : y : doubleEveryOther zs
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to generalize the problem a bit: Since we want to double every 2nd element *from the end*, we can't know in advance if it'll be every odd or even from the start. So the easiest way is to construct both, count if the overall size is even or odd, and then decide.

Let's define an `Applicative` data structure that captures:

- Having two variants of values,
- keeping the parity of the length (odd/even), and
- alternating the two when two such values are combined,

as follows:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Traversable as T

data Switching m = Switching !Bool m m
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Functor Switching where
    fmap f (Switching b x y) = Switching b (f x) (f y)

instance Applicative Switching where
    pure x = Switching False x x
    (Switching False f g) <*> (Switching b2 x y) = Switching b2 (f x) (g y)
    (Switching True  f g) <*> (Switching b2 x y) = Switching (not b2) (f y) (g x)
```

So traversing a list will yield two lists looking like this:

```
x1 y2 x3 y4 ...
y1 x2 y3 x4 ...
```

two zig-zag-ing copies. Now we can compute

```
double2 :: (Num m) => m -> Switching m
double2 x = Switching True (2 * x) x

double2ndRight :: (Num m, T.Traversable f) => f m -> f m
double2ndRight k = case T.traverse double2 k of
                    Switching True _ y -> y
                    Switching False x _ -> x
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are mine two solutions, note that I'm complete beginner in Haskell.

First one uses list functions, **head**, **tail** and **lenght**:

```
doubleSecondFromEnd :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleSecondFromEnd [] = []  -- Do nothing on empty list
doubleSecondFromEnd n
  | length n `mod` 2 == 0 = head n * 2 : doubleSecondFromEnd (tail n)
  | otherwise      = head n : doubleSecondFromEnd (tail n)
```

Second one, similar but with a different approach only uses **length** function:

```
doubleSecondFromEnd2 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleSecondFromEnd2 [] = []  -- Do nothing on empty list
doubleSecondFromEnd2 (x:y)
  | length y `mod` 2 /= 0 = x * 2 : doubleSecondFromEnd2 y
  | otherwise      = x : doubleSecondFromEnd2 y
```

Comment: Note there are Prelude functions `even` and `odd` that return a boolean with the parity of the element

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was:

```
doubleOdd (x:xs) = (2*x):(doubleEven xs)
doubleOdd [] = []
doubleEven (x:xs) = x:(doubleOdd xs)
doubleEven [] = []
```

DiegoNolan's solution is more elegant, in that the function and sequence length are more easily altered, but it took me a moment to grok.

Adding the requirement to operate *from the right* makes it a little more complex. `foldr` is a neat starting point for doing something from the right, so let me try:

```
doubleOddFromRight = third . foldr builder (id,double,[])
    where third (_,_,x) = x
          builder x (fx,fy,xs) = (fy, fx, fx x : xs)
          double x = 2 * x
```

This swaps the two functions `fx` and `fy` for each entry. To find the value of any entry will require a traversal to the end of the list, finding whether the length was odd or even.

Answer (score 1):

I am just learning **Haskell** so please find the following *beginner* solution. I try to use limited *cool* functions like `zipWith` , `cycle`, or `reverse`

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther s@(x:xs)
  | (length s) `mod` 2 == 0 = (x * 2) : (doubleEveryOther xs)
  | otherwise =  x : (doubleEveryOther xs)
```

The key thing to note that when doubling every element **from the right** you can put the doubling into two cases:

1. If the list is even length, you will ultimately end up doubling the first element of the list.
2. If the list is odd length, you will not be doubling the first element of the list.

I answered this as part of the homework assignment from [CS194](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

How about this for simplicity?

```
doubleEveryOtherRev :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

doubleEveryOtherRev l = doubleRev (reverse l) []
  where
    doubleRev [] a = a
    doubleRev (x:[]) a = (x:a)
    doubleRev (x:y:zs) a = doubleRev zs (2*y:x:a)
```

---

You would have to feed a reversed list of digits, in case you followed that course's recommendation, because it will double every other element as it reverses again. I think that this is different than using twice the reverse function, with another to double every other digit in between, because you won't need to know the full extent of their list by the second time. In other words, it solves that course's problem, but someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are missing a case: the case in which there are exactly two elements in the list, i.e. `doubleRev (x:y:[]) a = (y:2*x:a)`. Also, your result must be reversed in order to achieve what the OP wants.

Comment: Is it really necessary? I'm asking, because you don't want the last digit on that list to be doubled. Only the second to last and so on. Also, my explanation was that you would have to feed a reversed list of digits already, but I may have to write something new because of this: [numbers to digits in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell/61974129#61974129)

Comment: No you are not missing any cases.

Comment: @WillNess, I was thinking about using the function before the edit this way: `(doubleEveryOtherRev . reverse) l`. I did not explicitly show it, but yours is welcome as always.

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer to this [CIS 194](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html) homework assignment. It's implemented using just the stuff that was introduced in lecture 1 + `reverse`.

```
doubleEveryOtherLeftToRight :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherLeftToRight []       = []
doubleEveryOtherLeftToRight (x:[])   = [x]
doubleEveryOtherLeftToRight (x:y:zs) = x:y*2:(doubleEveryOtherLeftToRight zs)

doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther xs = reverse (doubleEveryOtherLeftToRight (reverse xs))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do it like this:

```
doubleEveryOther = reverse . zipWith (*) value . reverse
    where
    value = 1 : 2 : value
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Some answers seems not deal with odd/even length of list.

```
doubleEveryOtherEvenList = zipWith ($) (cycle [(*2),id])

doubleEveryOther :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleEveryOther n
    | length n `mod` 2 == 0 = doubleEveryOtherEvenList n
    | otherwise = (head n) : doubleEveryOtherEvenList (tail n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking an edx course in haskell, this is my noob solution.

```
doubleSecondR :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

doubleSecondR xs = reverse(zipWith (*) (reverse xs) ys)

where ys = repeat' [1,2]

repeat' :: [a] -> [a]

repeat' xs = xs ++ repeat' xs
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm too coming to this question from the [CIS 194](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/) course.

I did this two ways. First I figured that the point of the question should only rely on functions or ways of programming mentioned in either of the 3 possible sources listed. The [course lecture 1](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/01-intro.html), [Real World Haskell ch. 1,2](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/types-and-functions.html) and [Learn You a Haskell ch. 2](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out).

So OK:

- Recursion, conditionals
- `reverse`, basic functions like `max`, `min`, `odd`, `even`
- list functions e.g. `head`, `tail`, ...

Not OK:

- `foldr`, `foldl`, `map`
- Higher Order functions
- Anything beyond these

First solution, just using recursion with a counter:

```
doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther xs = loopDoubles xs 1

loopDoubles :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]
loopDoubles [] _ =  []
loopDoubles xs n =  loopDoubles (init xs) (n + 1) ++ [doubleEven (last xs) n]

doubleEven :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
doubleEven x n = if even n then x * 2 else x
```

This method uses recursion, but avoids calculating the length at each level of the recursion.

Second method breaking the aforemention rules of mine:

```
doubleEveryOther' :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther' xs =  map (\x -> if even (fst x) then (snd x) * 2 else snd x) $ zip (reverse [1..n]) xs
                        where n = length(xs)
```

This second one works by building up a reversed set of indexes and then mapping over these. This does calculate the length but only once.

e.g. `[1,1,1,1] -> [(4,1),(3,1),(2,1),(1,1)]`

Both of these are following the requirement of doubling every other element **from the right**.

```
> doubleEveryOther [1,2,3,4]
[2,2,6,4]
> doubleEveryOther [1,2,3]
[1,4,3]
> doubleEveryOther' [1,2,3,4]
[2,2,6,4]
> doubleEveryOther' [1,2,3]
[1,4,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the OP posed this question while researching an answer to the Homework 1 assignment from Haskell [CIS194 Course](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/lectures.html). Very little Haskell has been imparted to the student at that stage of the course, so while the above answers are correct, they're beyond the comprehension of the learning student because elements such as lambdas, function composition (.), and even library routines like length and reverse haven't been introduced yet. Here is an answer that matches the stage of teaching in the course:

```
doubleEveryOtherEven :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherEven []         = []
doubleEveryOtherEven (x:y:xs)   = x*2 : y : doubleEveryOtherEven xs

doubleEveryOtherOdd :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherOdd (x:[])      = [x] 
doubleEveryOtherOdd (x:y:xs)    = x : y*2 : doubleEveryOtherOdd xs

integerListLen :: [Integer] -> Integer
integerListLen []       = 0 
integerListLen (x:xs)   = 1 + integerListLen xs

doubleEveryOther :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOther xs
    | integerListLen xs `mod` 2 == 0    = doubleEveryOtherEven xs   -- also handles empty list case
    | otherwise                         = doubleEveryOtherOdd xs
```

The calculation requires foreknowledge on whether the list has an even or odd number of elements, to determine which digit in each pair of digits should be doubled. However, basic Haskell pattern-matching only permits matching list elements from left-to-right (example: x:xs), which means you can't determine if there are an odd or even number of elements until you've reached the end of the list, but by then it's too late since you need to do calculations on each left-hand pair of elements while working through the list to reach the end.

The solution is to split the doubling logic into two functions - one which handles even-length lists and another which handles odd-length lists. A third function is needed to determine which of those two functions to call for a given list, which in turn needs an additional function that can calculate the length of the list so we can establish whether the list has an odd or even number of elements (again, since the **length** library function hasn't been introduced at this stage of the course).

This solution is also in keeping with the advisory in the Week 1 lesson, which states: "*It’s good Haskell style to build up more complex functions by combining many simple ones.*"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for CIS 194 homework1.

I took idea from `toDigits` and `toDigitsRev`. It's not fancy, but works.

```
takeLastTwo :: [Int] -> [Int]
takeLastTwo [] = []
takeLastTwo (x : y : []) = [x, y]
takeLastTwo (x : xs) = takeLastTwo xs

removeLastTwo :: [Int] -> [Int]
removeLastTwo [] = []
removeLastTwo (x : y : []) = []
removeLastTwo (x : xs) = x : removeLastTwo xs

doubleEveryOther :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleEveryOther [] = []
doubleEveryOther (x : []) = [x]
doubleEveryOther (x : y : []) = (2 * x) : y : []
doubleEveryOther xs = doubleEveryOther (removeLastTwo xs) ++ doubleEveryOther (takeLastTwo xs)
```