# Scala - Double every 2nd element in list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I wanted to write a function that, given a list of `Int`s, returns a list in which every 2nd element has been doubled.

In Haskell the solution seems easy;

`double = zipWith ($) (cycle [id,(*2)])` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383169/haskell-double-every-2nd-element-in-list)

Whats the most idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

Comment: `list.zipWithIndex.map(x => x._1*(1+(1&x._2)))`

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to create a `Stream` of ones and twos, then `zip` your `List` with this `Stream`. This creates a `List` of pairs: `map` through this `List` and multiply the tuple elements.

```
val oneTwoCycle: Stream[Int] = List(1, 2).toStream #::: oneTwoCycle

val data = (1 to 10).toList

val altDoubled = data.zip(oneTwoCycle).map(x => x._1 * x._2)
// List(1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 9, 20)
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers so far are hardwired to do what the poster specifically requested (i.e double every second element), but the Haskell implementation is a lot more flexible - the list of functions can easily be extended to do something different to, say, every first, second, third element.

Here's a Scala version that similarly uses a list of functions to cycle through

```
val fns = List[Int=>Int](identity, {x => x *2})
val xs = List(1,2,3,4)

def cycle[T](x:List[T]) = Iterator.continually(x).flatten.toIterable
val ys = xs zip cycle(fns)
ys map { case (v, f) => f(v)}

// List(1, 4, 3, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite as concise Haskell, but it is pretty readable

```
(1 to 10).zipWithIndex.map { case (num, i) =>
  if (i % 2 == 1) num * 2 else num
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most idiomatic but one solution could be

```
scala> def double(list: List[Int]) = list.zipWithIndex.map{case (elem, index) => if(index==1) elem*2 else elem}
double: (list: List[Int])List[Int]

scala> double(List(1, 2, 3))
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3)
```

Or if you want every 2nd element within the same list to be doubled up,

```
scala> def double(list: List[Int]) = list.zipWithIndex.map{case (elem, index) => if((index+1)%2 == 0) elem*2 else elem}
double: (list: List[Int])List[Int]

scala> double(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12)
```

Comment: How about `list.zipWithIndex.map{case(elem, 1)=> elem*2 case(elem, _)=>elem}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
scala> val list = (1 to 10).toList
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> list.view.zipWithIndex.map(x => if(x._2 %2 != 0) 2*x._1 else x._1).toList
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 9, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest but fun to write with recursion and pattern matching.

```
 def double(xs: List[Int]) =  {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def doubleR(xs: List[Int], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match{
      case Nil      => acc 
      case h::Nil   => (h +: acc) 
      case h::ht::t => doubleR(t, ht * 2 +: h +: acc)
    }
    doubleR(xs, List[Int]()).reverse
  }
```

Test

```
scala> double(List(1,2,3,4,5))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 8, 5)
```