# Non-exhaustive pattern error in recursive function

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am trying to use recursion and higher-order functions to do something to the first element of a list and then to every other element in the list, so for example add 3 to the 1st, 3rd, 5th.. etc.

The problem I am having is that it gives me the `non-exhaustive pattern` error. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
applyToEveryOther :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
applyToEveryOther _ [] = []
applyToEveryOther f (x:y:xs) = f x : applyToEveryOther f xs
```

and these are some additional lines that I have tried but don't help:

```
applyToEveryOther _ [x] = f x
applyToEveryOther f [x] = f x
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell: Double every 2nd element in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383169/haskell-double-every-2nd-element-in-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single element case should also return a List (of type `[b]`):

```
applyToEveryOther f [x] = [f x]
```

Comment: If I have another question on this.. if I wanted to actually keep the whole list, not just keep the ones that got transformed, how would I go about doing this. I'm new to this and wasn't sure if I make a new post or not

Comment: @loutej definitely a new post! (I think the answer is `f x : y : applyToEveryOther f xs` but it'll be formatted better and more useful to others as a fresh post).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that doesn't use explicit recursion, but just higher-order functions:

```
import Data.List (cycle)

applyToEveryOther f = zipWith ($) (cycle [f, id])
```

`cycle` creates an infinite list of alternating functions `f`, `id`, `f`, `id`, etc.

`zipWith ($)` applies the functions in the list to the corresponding elements of your input list.

```
[(+1), id, (+1), id, (+1), id, (+1), id, ...]
[   1,  2,    3,  4,    5,  6,    7,  8     ]
=============================================
[   2,  2,    4,  4,    6,  6,    8,  8     ]
```

(Hat tip: the problem of applying a list of functions piecewise to a list of arguments, along with a solution using `zipWith ($)`, [appeared recently](https://twitter.com/1HaskellADay/status/921389376931758081) on the 1HaskellADay twitter feed.)

(My own inferior solution was to use the `ZipList` type constructor found in `Control.Applicative`; applied here, it would look something like

```
import Control.Applicative

applyToEveryOther f xs = let fs = cycle [f,id]
                          in getZipList (ZipList fs <*> ZipList xs)
```

)