# Take elements on even positions from the list

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, fold, type-mismatch

Problem: using *fold*, take from the list elements which are on the even positions:

```
GHCi> evenOnly [1..10]
 [2,4,6,8,10]
GHCi> evenOnly ['a'..'z']
 "bdfhjlnprtvxz"

evenOnly :: [a] -> [a]
evenOnly = undefined
```

I decided at first to get a list of alternating `0`-es and `1`-s: `[0,1,0,1..]`

```
Prelude> let g = iterate (\x -> (x + 1) `mod` 2) 0
Prelude> take 10 $ g
[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
```

Then *zip* it with the original list, getting a list of pairs: `[(x1, 0), (x2,1), (x3,0) .. (xn, ?)]`:

```
Prelude> zip g [1,2,3,4,5]
[(0,1),(1,2),(0,3),(1,4),(0,5)]
```

After that, `foldr` the list of pairs with a filtering function and an empty list as initialization value.

So I thought that this would work:

```
evenOnly :: [a] -> [a]
evenOnly xs = let g = iterate (\x -> (x + 1) `mod` 2) 0
  in
  foldr (\ (x, n) s -> if n == 1 then x : s else s) [] . (zip g xs)
```

But it gives an error, that I don't understand:

```
foldr.hs:44:59: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> t0 (a1, Integer)’
                  with actual type ‘[(Integer, a)]’
    • Possible cause: ‘zip’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘(zip g xs)’
      In the expression:
        foldr (\ (x, n) s -> if n == 1 then x : s else s) [] . (zip g xs)
      In the expression:
        let g = iterate (\ x -> (x + 1) `mod` 2) 0
        in
          foldr (\ (x, n) s -> if n == 1 then x : s else s) [] . (zip g xs)
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at foldr.hs:42:10)
        evenOnly :: [a] -> [a] (bound at foldr.hs:42:1)
```

I think my idea is correct, I just did something wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(.)` is function composition but `zip g xs` is a list not a function. You can just apply the resulting list as the argument to `foldr` directly. Note you have the arguments `g` and `xs` in the wrong order:

```
evenOnly :: [a] -> [a]
evenOnly xs = let g = iterate (\x -> (x + 1) `mod` 2) 0
  in
  foldr (\ (x, n) s -> if n == 1 then x : s else s) [] (zip xs g)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is a perfectly reasonable approach:

```
evenOnly :: [a] -> [a]
evenOnly (_ : a : as) = a : evenOnly as
evenOnly _ = []
```

Another option is to use a list comprehension:

```
evenOnly as = [a | (a, True) <- zip as (cycle [False, True])]
```

The list comprehension version will likely be a bit more efficient if it fuses with other list processing functions.

Answer (score 2):

One ought not to calculate anything that doesn't need calculating. The choice is positional, it is already known in advance. Calculating the modulos, comparing with Booleans, is all superfluous work.

Instead, do *this*, then do *that*, and go on switching like that; *using `foldr`*, as asked:

```
evenly :: [t] -> [t]
evenly xs = foldr c z xs f g
   where
   c x r f g = f x (r g f)
```

Next we finish up the definitions, according to how each is used:

```
   z _ _  = []
   f _ xs = xs
   g x xs = x : xs
```

Comment: this reminds me of zip encoding with coroutining folds. if we take other solutions here which are based off zip -- esp the last one in Willem's answer, -- encode the zip as the switching folds, inline, fuse and simplify everything, we just might end up with the (equivalent of) this code.

Comment: Your pattern of passing the next function to use instead of a Boolean inspired [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101548/7509065).

Comment: @JosephSible that's nice to hear! will have a look. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just `zip` the above together with a sequence of numbers, like:

```
evenOnly :: [a] -> [a]
evenOnly = foldr (\(c, x) -> if c then (x:) else id) [] . zip (cycle [False, True])
```

Here `cycle [False, True]` thus generates an infinite list of `[False, True, False, True, …]`. In the `foldr` we check the corresponding value `c` that originates from the `cycle [False, True]`. If it is `True`, then we prepend the list with `x`, otherwise we just pass the result of the recursive call with `id`.

Or we can omit this, and use:

```
evenOnly :: [a] -> [a]
evenOnly = foldr (uncurry ($)) [] . zip (cycle [const id, (:)])
```

Comment: @DanielWagner: thanks for the suggestion, updated :)

Comment: @DanielWagner: shouldn't this be `foldl`? Since `foldr` moves in the opposite direction, and thus will have different behavior for lists with odd length than with even length?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment, because it was wrong both in the way you said and also in having bad laziness characteristics.