# Reverse every even element in Haskell list

Tags: list, haskell, element

In Haskell a list is given, but you should reverse every even element. For example the list

```
f ["rehtruF", "dooG", kcuL"]
```

should be changed  into

```
["Further", "Good" "Luck"]
```

We tried this function:

```
f [] = []
f [x] = []
f (xs:ys:xss) = (reverse xs):(f xss)
```

but unfortunately, it only reversed the first element and prints it out. Do you have any idea how we could change the code, so that every even element is reserved and the output is as demonstrated above?

Comment: hint: try `map reverse`

Comment: @assembly.jc that doesn't help here at all.

Comment: If you reduce by hand, you will first get `(reverse "rehtruF"):(f ["kcuL"])`, where the absense of `"Good"` is a definite clue that you have left something out of the result.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383169/haskell-double-every-2nd-element-in-list/17383354#17383354.  For your needs instead of the functions `*2` and `id` you'd want to use `id` and `reverse`.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR - this is the solution (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383169/haskell-double-every-2nd-element-in-list/17383354#17383354)) that Thomas M. DuBuisson alluded to in his comment. Oops.

---

You don't even need to explicitly iterate over the input. Imagine you had a list of functions `fs = [f0, f1, f2, ...]` and a list of values `xs = [x0, x1, x2, ...]`, and you want to get `[f0 x0, f1 x1, f2 x2, ...]`. You do that with `zipWith ($)`:

```
zipWith ($) fs xs  -- == [f0 $ x0, f1 $ x1, f2 $ x2, ...]
                   -- == [f0 x0, f1 x1, f2 x2, ...]
```

For your problem, your `fs` would be an alternating sequence of `reverse` and `id`, which you can produce with `cycle [reverse, id] == [reverse, id, reverse, id, ...]`

Putting this together,

```
f :: [String] -> [String]
f strings = zipWith ($) (cycle [reverse, id]) strings
        -- == [reverse strings0, id strings0, reverse strings2, id strings3, ...]
```

or simply

```
f :: [String] -> [String]
f = zipWith ($) (cycle [reverse, id])
```

Comment: cycling and zipping is also [superfluous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58327016/849891), just as the `mod` taking. :)

Comment: This is my favorite one so far.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you completely drop the `ys` element. What you actually want is *keep it as-is*, i.e. put it as-is in the result list.

```
f (xs:ys:xss) = reverse xs : ys : f xss
```

Note that GHC would have warned you about the unused `ys` binding, if you had turned on the `-Wall` option (which is generally a good idea for beginners). You can do that by executing the compiler/interpreter with `ghc -Wall YOURFILE.hs`, or by typing `:set -Wall` in a GHCi session.

Comment: The last element is also being dropped, in the singleton case.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the even elements in the list, the first thing is to find even elements, one of the ways to do that is to index each elements in the list firstly like:

```
zip [0..] xs
```

and then, we reverse the elements has even index:

```
if index `mod` 2 == 0 then reverse x else x
```

put them all as

```
f xs = map reverseEven (zip [0..] xs)
    where reverseEven (index, x) = if index `mod` 2 == 0 
                                   then reverse x else x
```

Answer (score 0):

One ought not to calculate anything that doesn't need calculating. No zipping, no cycling, no `mod` taking, [just pure function calling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534683/849891):

```
foo :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
foo xs = foldr (\ x r f g -> f x (r g f)) 
               (\ _ _ -> []) 
               xs 
               ((:) . reverse) 
               (:)
```

First element is considered to be at index 0, i.e. at even position, as is in the question.

```
> foo ["Further","Good","Luck"]
["rehtruF","Good","kcuL"]

> foo $ foo ["Further","Good","Luck"]
["Further","Good","Luck"]
```

With plain recursion, what the above `foldr`-based definition is doing is:

```
foo = f   where 
      f (x:xs)  =  reverse x : g xs
      g (x:xs)  =  x : f xs
```

, plus the obvious `[]`-handling cases.

With `foldr`, `[]` is checked for by `foldr` itself; with mutual recursion, it must be done by each of the two cooperating functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an extra variable, you can keep track if you are on an even element or an odd element. For example, here we are using `1` to mean odd and `0` to mean even:

```
f = f' 1
  where
    f' _ []     = []
    f' 1 (x:xs) = reverse x: f' 0 xs
    f' 0 (x:xs) = x: f' 1 xs
```