# What is the method of adding every 5th (or nth) element of a list?

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to work off an example provided from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383169/haskell-double-every-2nd-element-in-list/17383354) on StackOverflow. I'm misinterpreting it though. I want to strip every 5th element from the list and put them in another list together.

Here is my best attempt at it so far.

```
fifth(_:_:_:_xs) = xs fifth xs
fifth [] = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably better to separate your concerns: make a function that "*slices*" the list and takes every fifth element, and then sum that list.

```
fifth :: [a] -> [a]
fifth (x:_:_:_:_:xs) = x : fifth xs
fifth (x:_) = [x]
fifth [] = []
```

then you sum the list of elements with:

```
sumFifth :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumFifth = sum . fifth
```

Comment: I have to wait a period to accept answers, but you really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Can it be done without grabbing the first element?

Comment: @kevinmallone: you mean taking the items at index 4, 9, 14, etc.?

Comment: Exactly, sorry for my poor wording.

Comment: @kevinmallone: yes, you have to change the first pattern slightly and remove the second clause. I leave it as an exercise to change `fifth` accordingly.

Comment: Ha. I understand. I'll work on it now.
Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I made two changes. One of them just gave an empty list, and the other successfully started with the element at index 4, the fifth element, but it was a mess after that. I updated my post to reflect the current state of my confusion.

Comment: @kevinmallone: you were close `fifth(_:_:_:_:x:xs) = x : fifth xs`

Comment: Ahhh. Man. I really was haha. Thanks a lot.